# No bootable device USB 2.0 MacBook Pro mid 2014

Tags: bootcamp, usb, windows, dual-boot, bootable-disk

I've been tearing my hair out the last couple days trying to get Windows installed. 
I have a MacBook Pro Retina 15 inch mid 2014. Yosemite version 10.10.1.
Win 7 64 bit iso (sha1 - 0bcfc54019ea175b1ee51f6d2b207a3d14dd2b58).

I have tried two usb 2.0 flash drives with 'Create a Windows 7 or later install disk' option in BCA. This proceeds smoothly and so does creating the partition using Install Windows 7 option.  However, when it restarts, it says something along the lines of 'no bootable device'  If I hold down 'alt', the only options are to boot back into OS X & the recovery disk.

I realise this question has been asked countless times - I have read a lot of them but few seem applicable to my situation and those that are have not helped yet. I have not tried another USB yet since I am bandwidth limited (both in download speed and data limit) and BCA wants to redownload Windows support files every time and at this point it feels like a shot in the dark.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.  Some further questions:

- Is there a way to determine whether the usb drives are at fault?
- Does BCA create the bootable drive in any special way? I.e. is it possible to create it by another method that will still play well with the bootcamp process?

Comment: The ReFind Boot Manager needs a special mention here - it saves a lot of complications by using it to manage the boot process on a Mac: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Installing Windows 7 or 10 Pro 64 bit without DVD or Flash Drive

If you are trying to install Windows 7 on a 2012 through 2014 Mac, then you should read [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383807/mac-running-windows-7-unable-to-detect-mac-hard-ware-windows-support-software-i/384068#384068) to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/383807/mac-running-windows-7-unable-to-detect-mac-hard-ware-windows-support-software-i).

> Special thanks to user [Rafa](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/116090/rafa), who was able to correct this procedure so it now works with Windows 10.

Here I assume your computer is configured as required by the Boot Camp Assistant. (In other words, you will be installing Windows to the 4th partition on disk 0.) Also, your [firmware is up to date](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518) and you have downloaded the correct "[Boot Camp Support Software](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016)" for your model Mac computer. **Before starting, remove all DVD's and external devices from your Mac.**

> Note: Some of the steps, *that do not involve VirtualBox*, have images captured from a VirtualBox window. This was done when this was the easiest way to create an illustration. I suppose I could have cropped the images, but I chose not to.

(Hint: For a better view, click on an image or open an image in a new window.)

1. Create a MS-DOS (FAT) formatted partition on your Macs internal
   drive. This is where Windows 7 will be installed. You can use the
   Bootcamp Assistant, the Disk Utility, or commands (`distutil`, `gpt`
   and/or `fdisk`) entered in a Terminal window. Other third party
   tools, such as [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/), can also be used. Give the label for
   this partition the name "BOOTCAMP". When finished, quit all
   applications.

   > This procedure requires the "BOOTCAMP" partition be the 4th partition on your Macs internal drive (disk0). If you are using the
   > Disk Utility from OS X 10.7 or newer and your Mac has the default
   > drive configuration, then the new "BOOTCAMP" partition should be
   > created as the 4th partition automatically. However, if you are using APFS and the default drive configuration, then the new "BOOTCAMP" partition should be
   > created as the 3th partition automatically.
2. Make sure the drive is using the GPT/MBR hybrid partitioning scheme. See my answer to the question "[How to convert a drive from the GPT format to the hybrid GPT/MBR format when using High Sierra (macOS 10.13.2)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308824/how-to-convert-a-drive-from-the-gpt-format-to-the-hybrid-gpt-mbr-format-when-usi)" for a procedure that accomplishes this task.

   > User [Semi](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/272920/semi) has noted that the Boot Camp Assistant (BCA) will correctly GPT/MBR hybrid partition the drive. So, you may be able to the the BCA to partition the drive, then use the flash drive to install Windows.
3. Download and install a free copy of [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org). I used
   VirtualBox 5.0.14 r105127, Copyright © 2016.
4. Do the following to transfer the "Boot Camp Support Software" to a
   partition compatible with VirtualBox. Create folder named
   "VirtualBox" in your Documents folder. Open the Disk Utility and
   from the menu bar select **File->New->Blank Disk Image**. Create
   this image in the "VirtualBox" folder using the following
   parameters.

   [image: 1]

   Using the Finder application, copy the "Boot Camp Support Software"
   to this new partition. When finish, this new partition should appear
   in the Finder as shown below. (For readers with older Macs, you may
   only have the "BootCamp" folder.)

   [image: 2]
5. This step will create the file needed by VirtualBox to access the
   partition containing the "Boot Camp Support Software". In a Terminal
   application window, enter the following commands.

   > Note: I assume you are using the default Bourne-Again Shell (bash).

   ```
   cd  ~/documents/virtualbox
   open  bcss.dmg
   DISK1=$(mount|awk  -F  s1  '/BCSS/{print$1}')
   diskutil  unmountDisk  $DISK1
   vboxmanage  internalcommands  createrawvmdk  -filename  "$PWD/bcss.vmdk"  -rawdisk  $DISK1
   ```

   The result should be the creation of the file `bcss.vmdk` in your
   "VirtualBox" folder. Later, you will select this file to give a
   virtual machine access to this partition.

   > Note: At this point, one should realize it would be easier to copy the commands from this document and paste them into the Terminal
   > application window.
6. This step will create the files needed by VirtualBox to access the
   physical partition where you will install Windows. In a Terminal
   application window, enter the following commands.

   ```
   cd  ~/documents/virtualbox
   DISK0=/dev/disk0
   PARTITION=4
   PARTID="$DISK0"s"$PARTITION"
   diskutil  unmount  $PARTID 
   sudo  chmod  go+rw  $PARTID
   sudo  vboxmanage  internalcommands  createrawvmdk  -filename  "$PWD/bootcamp.vmdk"  -rawdisk  $DISK0  -partitions  $PARTITION
   sudo  chown  $USER  bootcamp*.vmdk
   ```

   > Note: This access granted by the `chmod` command will only last
   > until OS X is rebooted.

   The result should be the creation of the files `bootcamp.vmdk` and
   `bootcamp-pt.vmdk` in your "VirtualBox" folder. Later, you will
   select the file `bootcamp.vmdk` to give a virtual machine access to
   the physical partition.

   > Note: OS X prefers to automount file systems. This can be disabled for a particular partition by creating or modifying the `/etc/fstab`
   > file. Instead of employing the `/etc/fstab` file, the user is asked
   > to repeatedly enter the following commands.
   >
   > ```
   > diskutil  unmount  $PARTID;diskutil  unmountDisk  $DISK1
   > ```
   >
   > These commands unmount the physical "BOOTCAMP" partition and the disk image file `bcss.dmg` containing the "BCSS" partition.
7. Configure the virtual machine. Open the VirtualBox application and
   click on icon above the New label. Enter or select the values shown
   below, then click the "Continue" button.

   [image: 2000]

   Use the default settings except for the hard drive. Choose the "Use
   an existing virtual hard drive file" button. Navigate to your
   "VirtualBox" folder. Highlight the `bootcamp.vmdk` file. Before
   clicking the "Open" button, enter the following commands in the same
   Terminal application window.

   ```
   diskutil  unmount  $PARTID;diskutil  unmountDisk  $DISK1
   ```

   Open the `bootcamp.vmdk` file. Your window should appear similar to
   what is shown below.

   [image: 2001]

   Click the "Create" button.

   After returning to the VirtualBox application's "Oracle VM
   VirtualBox Manager" window, click on the icon above the
   "Settings" label. Next, click on the icon above the "Storage" label.
   In the "Storage Tree", "Controller: SATA" should be highlighted.
   Right click on this highlighted area and select "Add Hard Disk".
   Choose the "Use an existing virtual hard drive file" button.
   Navigate to your "VirtualBox" folder. Highlight the `bcss.vmdk`
   file. Before clicking the "Open" button, enter the following
   commands in the same Terminal application window.

   ```
   diskutil  unmount  $PARTID;diskutil  unmountDisk  $DISK1
   ```

   Open the `bcss.vmdk` file. **Next, select the "Use Host I/O Cache"
   option.** Your window should appear similar to what is shown below.

   [image: 2002]

   Highlight the Empty CD/DVD and select "Choose Virtual Optical Disk
   File..." to attach your Windows 7 iso file. (Hint: Look for the
   CD/DVD icons)

   [image: 2003]

   Click OK to close the window. Your "Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager"
   window should appear similar to what is shown below.

   [image: 2004]
8. In this step, you will copy the necessary files to the physical
   partition, so later you can restart your Mac and install Windows.
   Enter the following commands in the same Terminal application
   window.

   ```
   diskutil  unmount  $PARTID;diskutil  unmountDisk  $DISK1
   ```

   Next, click on the icon above the "Start" label to boot from the
   Windows 7 iso file. Press the space bar, if prompted to "Press any
   key to boot from CD or DVD."

   > Note: The mouse pointer must be over the virtual machine screen window before you press the space bar.

   When the display below appears, click the "Next" button.

   [image: 100]

   When the display below appears, click the "Install now" button.

   [image: 101]

   The message "Setup is Starting…" should appear, followed by the display shown below.

   [image]

   Reaching this point causes any necessary drivers to be loaded. Next, click on the red box with the white "X". If prompted, click on "Yes". When the display below appears, select "Repair your computer".

   [image: 101]

   With the button "Use recovery tools that can help fix problems
   starting Windows." selected, click the Next button.

   [image: 102]

   Select the "Command Prompt" option.

   [image: 103]

   Insure the drive letters `C` through `F` are not assigned by default
   to a volume by entering the following commands.

   ```
   mountvol  c:  /d  >nul
   mountvol  d:  /d  >nul
   mountvol  e:  /d  >nul
   mountvol  f:  /d  >nul
   ```

   Enter the following to determine a list of the current volumes.

   ```
   diskpart
   list  volume
   ```

   The image below displays the volumes found on my Mac. You may get
   different results.

   [image: 9000]

   Enter the following commands, to assign the drive letters `D`, `C`
   and `E` to the CD-ROM volume and the volumes labeled "BOOTCAMP" and
   "BCSS", respectively. In the image shown above, these are volumes 0,
   3 and 4. If your volume indices are different, make the appropriate
   substitutions. Also, NTFS format the "BOOTCAMP" volume.

   ```
   select  volume  3
   assign  letter=c
   format  quick  fs=ntfs  label=BOOTCAMP
   select  volume  0
   assign  letter=d
   select  volume  4
   assign  letter=e
   list  volume
   exit
   ```

   When finished, the volume letters should appear similar to what is
   shown below.

   [image: 9001]

   Next, enter the commands givens below. The `bootsect` command writes
   boot code to a Volume Boot Record (VBR) of a partition and Master
   Boot Record (MBR) of the corresponding drive.

   ```
   bootsect  /nt60  c:  /mbr
   bootsect  /nt60  e:  /mbr
   ```

   The next sequence of commands creates a Virtual Hard Disk (VHD)
   file. The VHD represents a virtual flash drive from which Windows
   will be installed on to the physical "BOOTCAMP" partition.

   > Note: If you are installing Windows 10, then the parameter `fs=fat32`, in the `format` command shown below, should be replaced
   > with `fs=ntfs`.

   ```
   diskpart
   create  vdisk  file=c:\flashdrive.vhd  maximum=8000  type=fixed 
   attach  vdisk
   create  partition  primary
   format  quick  fs=fat32  label=FLASHDRIVE
   assign  letter=f
   exit
   ```

   Finally, copy the Windows installer iso and "Boot Camp Support
   Software" files first to VHD, then directly to the physical
   partition where Windows is to be installed. Exit the Command Prompt
   window when finished.

   ```
   xcopy  d:*  f:  /s  /h
   xcopy  e:*  f:  /s  /y
   xcopy  f:*  c:  /s  /h
   exit
   ```

   > Note: The files `\sources\boot.wim` and `\sources\install.wim` take a long time to copy. The file sizes are 168 MB and 2.95 GB,
   > respectively.

   Select the "Shut Down" button to shutdown the virtual machine. Quit
   the VirtualBox application.
9. This step will involve configuring Master Boot Record (MBR) of your
   physical internal drive. The MBR is stored on the first 512 bytes of
   this drive. This space is shared by boot code and the MBR partition
   table.

   > **This step can not be preformed under OS X 10.11 (El Capitan) with System Integrity Protection (SIP) turn on.** (This is the default
   > setting.) If you are using OS X 10.11, you must disable SIP,
   > complete this step, then restore SIP. See the link: [How do I
   > disable System Integrity Protection (SIP) AKA “rootless” on OS X
   > 10.11, El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-os-x-10-11?lq=1).

   In a Terminal application window, enter the following commands. The
   first `fdisk` command flags the "BOOTCAMP" partition as the active
   partition. The second `fdisk` command changes the "BOOTCAMP"
   partition id to 7. The final `fdisk` command copies the boot code
   from the MBR of the disk containing the "Boot Camp Support Software"
   partition to the MBR of the physical disk containing the "BOOTCAMP"
   partition.

   ```
   cd  ~/documents/virtualbox
   DISK0=/dev/disk0
   PARTITION=4
   PARTID="$DISK0"s"$PARTITION"
   open  bcss.dmg
   DISK1=$(mount|awk  -F  s1  '/BCSS/{print$1}')
   INPUT=$(printf  "f  $PARTITION\nq\ny")
   sudo  fdisk  -e  $DISK0  <<<"$INPUT"  &>/dev/null
   INPUT=$(printf  "s  $PARTITION\n7\nq\ny")
   sudo  fdisk  -e  $DISK0  <<<"$INPUT"  &>/dev/null
   sudo  fdisk  -u  -y  -f  $DISK1  $DISK0
   diskutil  mount  $PARTID
   ```

   > Note: To display the value for the variable INPUT, use the command `echo "$INPUT"`.
10. This is the step where you install Windows to your "BOOTCAMP"
    partition. Restart your Mac and hold down the <kbd>option/alt</kbd>
    key. Select the Windows icon to boot from the "BOOTCAMP" partition.
    Open a Command Prompt window, by navigating through the displays as you did in step 8. Enter the commands below to attach the "FLASHDRIVE" partition stored in the Virtual Hard Disk (VHD) file.

    ```
    diskpart
    select  vdisk  file=c:\flashdrive.vhd
    attach  vdisk  readonly
    list  volume
    exit
    ```

    On my Mac, the output from the `list volume` command shows `E` to
    be the drive letter assigned to the "FLASHDRIVE" partition. If your
    drive letter is different, make the correct substitution when
    entering the `e:\setup` command given at the end of this step. Next,
    remove all the files, but one, from the "BOOTCAMP" partition.

    ```
    rmdir  /s  /q  c:\
    ```

    > If the above command executes correctly, you should get the error message: "c:\flashdrive.vhd - The process cannot access the file
    > because it is being used by another process."

    Start installing Windows 7 by entering the command given below.
    Select "BOOTCAMP" as your installation partition.

    ```
    e:\setup
    ```

    The installation files are stored in the "FLASHDRIVE" partition.
    Since this partition is stored as a VHD file in the "BOOTCAMP"
    partition, do not try to reformat the "BOOTCAMP" partition. You will
    remove these installation files in a later step. When your Mac
    restarts, it will boot to OS X. This is to be expected. From the
    "System Preferences" select Windows as your startup disk and restart
    the Mac. Your Windows installation will continue.
11. Once Windows finishes installing, the "Boot Camp Support Software"
    can be applied. To access this software, the `c:\flashdrive.vhd`
    file, containing the "FLASHDRIVE" partition, needs to be attached.
    Click on the "Start" button, type in `diskmgmt.msc` and hit the
    <kbd>return</kbd> key. Once in Disk Management, click on **Action**
    in the menu bar and select **Attach VHD**. Select the file location
    and check "Read-only" to prevent writes to the VHD  file. After you
    hit "OK", the drive will show up in Disk  Management with a blue
    icon. Close Disk Management.

    In the AutoPlay popup window, select "Open folder to view files."
    (If no popup appears, use the Windows Explorer to open the drive
    labeled "FLASHDRIVE".) The `setup.exe` file can be found in the
    folder labeled  "BootCamp". Execute this application to install the
    "Boot Camp Support Software". The VHD file will detach when the
    computer restarts.
12. Finally, remove DVD and "Boot Camp Support Software" folders and
    files.  This can be accomplished by dragging the
    `c:\flashdrive.vhd` file to the Recycle Bin. If you get an error
    message about the file being open, restart the computer and try
    again.

### Clean Up

The "Virtual Box" folder can be deleted. You will probably need to eject the "BCSS" partition first.

You can delete the "BootCamp" virtual machine. This can be done from the VirtualBox application. If VirtualBox does not remove all the files, you can remove them manually. Look in the `~/"VirtualBox VMs"` folder.

You can delete the Windows 7 iso file.

You can remove the VirtualBox application, but since it takes such little space, I would not bother.

Comment: Dear David, your tutorial is a **materpiece**. I take a while to have success in the process, but now I am typing from Windows 10 in my iMac 2009. - I made some changes (like my disk is disk1s3 because I use SSD + HDD) and I used Windows' UI ('Explorer' from the Installer) to copy BCSS and Windows files to the FLASHDRIVE, because in cmd I was getting errors, Anyway, thanks for your help, really usefull and detailed!

Comment: Oh, and suggestions: use quotation marks on ```$PWD/bcss.vmdk```, because new users can have space in their disk name (like "Mac HD"). And in ```create  paritition  primary``` the right is ```partition```.

Comment: @Hugo: Thanks for the corrections. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Hugo: How did you launch the Windows UI (Explorer) from the installer?

Comment: Windows 10 shows "advanced options" and "Microsoft tools to try resolving" (something like that) when selected 'Repair computer' instead of Intall. First I used CMD (on advanced options)  to format FLASHDRIVE, assign letter=s, etc. after I came back for Microsoft Tools (where Explorer is), so manually copied everything to FLASHDRIVE.

Comment: What's the point in setting environment variables you only use once or twice?

Comment: @Max: The genesis of this answer is [Boot camp install of Windows 7 issue, no bootable devices](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179486/boot-camp-install-of-windows-7-issue-no-bootable-devices/180263#180263), where the use of environment variable made more sense. This reincarnation assumes a Mac has only one internal drive. Based on [user Hugo's success](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/226262/boot-camp-flash-drive-not-showing-on-boot-for-late-2009-imac), the next generation of this procedure should work for Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10 with Macs containing 1 or 2 internal drives.

Comment: @Max: Originally, I set variable `DISK1` to `/dev/disk1`, but user klanomoath pointed out this would be wrong if Core Storage is being used. User Hugo needed to change `DISK0` to `/dev/disk1` and `PARTITION` to `3`. So the use of variables makes substitutions easier.. Also, once the variables are set, one can cut and paste the commands rather than typing them in.

Comment: Just to let others know that I followed this procedure and successfully installed Windows 10 alongside OS X 10.11 in my late 2011 MBP 17'. The copy errors that @hugo mentioned are due to the fact that on Windows 10 some setup files are larger than 4G and the Virtual Hard Disk is FAT32, which cannot accommodate them, so the first `xcopy` instruction fails. If you format the VHD with NTFS everything works.

Comment: @Rafa: Your correction has been entered in the procedure.

Comment: Can you use Bootcamp to partition instead of Disk Utility?

Comment: @ Razgriz: Yes, you can use the Boot Camp Assistant application.

Comment: I just finished installing Win7 in my Macbook Pro using your guide and it works very well. Maybe it's worth noting in your steps that you can use Bootcamp if you prefer that over Disk Utility. DU took a long while partitioning my hard drive that I had to bail out on it, luckily, I was still able to repartition and didn't have to deal with a "phantom missing space". Also, in step 7, at "list volume", I only saw the CD, BootCamp, and BCSS but everything still worked as intended.

Comment: Also, it may not be as "straightforward" for other people, but if you encounter the Windows 8 Recovery instead of the Windows 7 one, just go to "Advanced", then "Command Prompt". I forgot to take screen caps.

Comment: I've completed steps 1-8, but the windows partition doesn't show up during the option boot in step 9. Running OSX 10.11.5, on a 15 inch early-2011 macbook pro. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sir: Which version of windows are you installing? Are you sure you are installing to partition 4 on disk 0? You could post a new question and we could try to diagnose what went wrong. The procedure, if implemented correctly, should work for your model Mac.

Comment: Thank you so much! The crazy genius David. I've managed to install windows7 ultimate on my iMac 27" ,Mid 2010 in the third try. I am using Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan. My first two attemptions both failed at the step to open command line tool, as I encountered an error when click "Reparing this computer" , I guess the happens because the wrong windows ISO I downloaded.

Comment: Trying this on MacOS High Sierra. The BootCamp Assistant sets the partition to partition 3, so I had to change the `PARTITION` variable to `3`. I'm currently at step 8, and the last fdisk command `sudo  fdisk  -u  -y  -f  $DISK1  $DISK0` does not seem to work. I have no problems doing it to just `$DISK1`, but there seems to be a problem with `$DISK0`. It gives the error " `disk` is not of the form /dev/rdisk0"

Comment: Ignore the above comment. For macOS High Sierra users here, you guys might have to reset the laptop first, then do step 8. I think this has something to do with using the same terminal window for the duration of the process. The variable values got messed up and you gotta reset at least terminal, then do step 8.

Comment: Trying on High Sierra, I've gotten to starting up the VM, but whenever I go to Repair your computer on the Windows setup screen, I always get "This version of System Recovery Options is not compatible with the version of windows you are trying to repair." Is this caused by the iso?

Comment: @Noir Antares: I can not image a High Sierra user needing to use this antiquated answer. Which version of Windows are you trying to install and what is the model/year of your Mac? I probably could recommend a procedure that is easier to implement.

Comment: @David Anderson I'm trying to install a Win7 Ultimate x64 on mid-2010 Macbook pro

Comment: @DavidAnderson I want Win7 x64 on my Mac Pro 2013. If you have a proven method that'll get around Apples' intransigent 'no-Win7-for-you' lockout on BootCamp that's shorter than this, please do share it.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I followed your guide to the letter and was able to install Windows 7 on a late 2011 MacBook Pro without using USB or a disc :)

Comment: @DavidAnderson Holy cow, man... this guide is incredible, in its preciseness. It got me up and running on my old MBP, with no hiccups. Thank you so much!

Comment: I believe I did everything right, even using the same version of VirtualBox mentioned. All steps seemed to have gone smoothly. When I restart in step 10 I only see the default Mac HD and no BOOTCAMP option. When I log back in to the Mac I see BOOTCAMP mounted still. I even tried step 9 again. I've so far been unable to find any clues searching around. I may start from the beginning again when I get some time.

Comment: @Rafe: What is the model/year of your Mac? What version of macOS do you currently have installed? Which version of Windows are you installing?

Comment: Oh sorry! MBP Late 2011 13" intel core i5, running High Sierra (10.13.6), installing Windows 7 SP1 x64 x86 (I tried the 32bit too). Is there anything I can look for to debug the part that causes the mounted BOOTCAMP partition to show as bootable? P.S. I'm only doing this because I do not have DVD-R (and I think the burner is broken anyway). I may try the external USB stick method if this won't work but I'll wait to see if any advice shows up here before doing that)

Comment: Other (perhaps easier) methods exist that have been created since this answer was posted. I do not think you can boot the Windows 7 installer from a USB port. I believe you can boot the Windows 10 installer from a USB port and then use commands to install Windows 7.

Comment: Any thoughts on how I might debug this method? To get it to show up as a boot option?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a new enough Mac to install using a USB flash drive and I have not created one recently enough to remember what is stored on it. You can mount the iso file and I believe you should be able to compare with the content on the flash drive. But again I am not sure.

Your external USB ports are both USB 3 and that might just be the problem. The Windows 7 installer may not work with USB 3 ports. Do you suppose Apple expects you to use an external optical (DVD) drive?

It is possible to install Windows 7 without the use of a USB flash drive or a optical DVD drive. The process is tedious and I will not go into the steps unless you are interested. You will need to download free third party software to do so.

Did you download the "Boot Camp Support Software" and follow the steps outlined at the site given below?

[Install Windows 7 and earlier on your Mac using Boot Camp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016)

Comment: I hope they dont expect me to use an external optical drive.  The method you refer to, is that making use of eg virtual box?  I've so far stuck with bootcamp as I *really* want to avoid messing up my drive (this has happened to me so many times on windows).

Comment: I did not download the software separately no, it happens as part of the process in BCA to make a bootable usb.  I followed all of the other steps though

Comment: I purpose of downloading the _**Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5640**_ was to save on your limited bandwidth. The files use 1.36 GB of space and once this step in completed you should not have to repeat it. You are correct, the third party software is VirtualBox. The installer for VirtualBox is a 91 MB file, so it should download fairly quickly. One advantage to having VirtualBox installed, is you could then boot from the Window 7 iso using a virtual machine to see if the iso is any good.  You could then copy these files to your Boot Camp partition and install windows on your physical Mac.

Comment: Unfortunately if I test a new usb I have no choice regarding the download of the windows support software - the box cannot be unchecked.  Have you used the virtualbox method before? Are you aware of any dangers in using that method? I do already have virtualbox installed.

Comment: Yes, I have used VirtualBox to install Windows to physical partition on my 2007 iMac. If you wish, I could post a tutorial where you would employ the procedure to install Windows on a virtual machine. You could then try the procedure for yourself. This should be fairly safe, since you would be only working in a virtual environment. Later, I could post how to do the same, using the physical BOOTCAMP partition on your Mac. Here, VirtualBox would only be used to copy the files to the physical partition. You would not use VirtualBox to do the physical install of Windows to the BOOTCAMP partition.

Comment: Thanks, I do know how to install to a virtual machine but this doesn't help me much as I require access to the gfx card. Instructions for installing to bootcamp partition would be welcome

Comment: OK, then I should assume you have a fairly good understand of how to use the Windows commands `DISKPART`, `XCOPY`, `BOOTSECT` and `BOOTREC`?

Comment: You will need to first create a physical partition to hold the Windows 7 operating system. If the BCA already created this partition you can use that one. Otherwise, use the Disk Utility or other utility to create this partition. The partition should be FAT formatted with the label BOOTCAMP. Afterwards, enter the following commands in a Terminal window and post the output to your question: `diskutil  list`, `sudo  fdisk  /dev/disk0` and `sudo  gpt  -r  show  /dev/disk0`. None of these commands will change your computer. Some may ask for your login password. This is normal.

Answer (score 0):

It so happened that I did a win10 install on my MacBook Air just yesterday, and I ran into exactly the same problem of seeing "no bootable partition", followed by having only two choices at the boot selection screen after power cycle. However, I didn't do anything special to get it working. I just restarted it again, while holding down the Option key from the beginning, and the USB (windows) showed up as one of the boot choices. I'll just list everything I can think of so that you might spot something:

- MacBook Air (mid 2012). Latest El Capitan 10.11.3. USB 2 flash drive (not USB 3).

  1. Download win10 64 bit installation ISO file from MS.
  2. Use BCA to create bootable installation drive on the flash drive, and download the boot camp files to the same drive. Create bootcamp partition (70GB)
  3. Remove a JetDrive that I had in the SD card slot. No other external drive except the USB flash drive
  4. Restart. Shows the "no bootable partition" message.
  5. Power down. Power back up, with Option key pressed. Only see "Macintosh HD" and "Recovery 10.11.3". Select "Macintosh HD".
  6. On desktop, check to make sure the USB drive has the right stuff (e.g. autorun.inf, setup.exe, boot directory, BootCamp directory, etc.)
  7. Restart. Hold the Option key when it starts to power up.
  8. Now it shows 4 choices on the boot screen: Macintosh HD, Recovery, USB (Windows), USB (EFI boot).
  9. Choose USB (Windows). Installation starts.

Comment: I am very interested in your success installing Windows 10. Your model is one of the *officially* supported models for Windows 10. In step 9 you chose a BIOS/MBR (i.e. Window) install over the EFI/GPT (i.e. EFI boot) install. I assume had no problems installing and were able to run "setup.exe" to install the "Boot Camp Support Software" afterwards? If you succeeded, this would confirm Windows 10 is still being installed using the legacy BIOS/MBR method on Macs that officially support Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, I selected the "Windows" option instead of the "EFI boot" option. So far, win10 is working fine in BootCamp. I was able to reinstall some of my old windows programs and run them without problems.

Comment: Remembered a couple more things. First is that I needed to disconnect/remove all external drives including what's in the SD card slot (step 3 above), or the windows installation refuses to use the bootcamp partition. The second is that after windows finished installing, the BCA support software started to install on its own, and eventually got stuck installing Realtek audio (?). Following some advice I found on the web, I just killed the realteksetup.exe task, and BCA can finish installing the rest. So far, everything seems to work fine (track pad, USB, SD card, wifi).