# Install Windows 10 on old Macbook Pro without optical drive

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, ssd

I'm looking to install Windows 10 on an old Macbook Pro (13 inch, early 2011), which I've replaced the HDD in with a SSD. I was able to do this using a flash drive, and managed to get everything working except the audio (Windows wouldn't recognize my computer's internal speakers).  After doing some research, it appears that this problem occurs when you install Windows via EFI boot, so the recommended solution is to install Windows using a burned DVD.  Unfortunately the optical drive in my Macbook is broken, so this method isn't available to me.  I have to tried to install Windows on a partition of my SSD using Virtual Box, but it's not clear to me how to get around the fact that my drive is a GPT partition scheme. (Windows 10 won't allow me to install to my BOOTCAMP partition because it is a GPT scheme)

In short, I would like to install Windows 10 in BIOS (to avoid audio issues) on a partition of my SSD without using the optical drive.  Any suggestions for accomplishing this would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [method](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521). If you have any problems or questions, post a comment below. BTW, this is not the only method that works. Other variations exist, so if this one does not work, I can suggest another.

Basically, you will be creating a virtual disk to replace the DVD or flash drive that you would normally use. You will be installing Windows to boot using the BIOS boot method. Good luck!