# Installing Windows 7 without DVD/Flash Drive - stuck at step 5

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I was following [this amazing guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521) on how to install Windows 7 without Bootcamp and got stuck at step 5. It should create files, but it didn't. I got the following result in Terminal:

[image]

After doing what David told me to do, I noticed it created the partition on 'disk0s5', or at least it has this as its identifier.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB         disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB       disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HDD                     749.7 GB       disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB       disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                249.5 GB       disk0s5
/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        +2.0 GB         disk1
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 BCSS                    2.0 GB         disk1s1
```

Is it alright to just switch things around and replace every Terminal command containing 'disk0s4' with 'disk0s5', so it locates the right partition?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: The instructions you are refer to install Windows on partition 4 of disk 0. In your case, you do not have a fourth partition on disk 0. This was suppose to be created in step 1. I suggest you run the Terminal application commands `diskutil list`, `sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk0` and `sudo fdisk /dev/disk0` and post the output to your question. Also, what is the model/year of your Mac.

Comment: I used Disk Utility to create a partition, just like the guide told me. I will update my post, as there is something strange going on - it created a partition on disk 5.

Comment: Restart the Mac and see if the Identifiers change.

Comment: @HaloLamp Please don't post text output in your shell as screenshot!

Answer (score 1):

Usually the OS X operating system is synchronized with the values stored in the GUID Partition Table (GPT). In other words, partition 4 in the table for `disk0` would be be identified as `/dev/disk0s4`. In your case, the identifier is `/dev/disk0s5`. The easiest way to resynchronize is to restart the Mac.