# Installing Windows 7 without DVD/Flash Drive - step 6: no permission?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I am following [this guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521), but cannot add the virtual hard disk at step 6. I get a 'No permission' pop-up.

[image]

How do I grant myself permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the commands, given in step 5 that prevents this error message from occurring, is repeated  below.

```
sudo  chown  $USER  bootcamp*.vmdk
```

This command changes ownership from the `root` user to the current user. In your case, I assume the current user is named `Nick`. To verify you entered this command correctly, you can enter the command below. Here I assume your current directory still is `~/Documents/VirtualBox`.

```
ls -l bootcamp*
```

In your case, the output should appear as shown below.

```
cd ~/Documents/VirtualBox
ls -l bootcamp*
-rw-------  1 Nick  staff  37376 14 sep 15:43 bootcamp-pt.vmdk
-rw-------  1 Nick  staff    682 14 sep 15:43 bootcamp.vmdk
```

From your comments, I assume this is what you currently would get.

```
cd ~/Documents/VirtualBox
ls -l bootcamp*
-rw-------  1 root  staff  37376 14 sep 15:43 bootcamp-pt.vmdk
-rw-------+ 1 root  staff    682 14 sep 15:43 bootcamp.vmdk
```

This output shows you are not the current owner of these files. Additionally, the `+` character indicates you have added extended security information such as an access control list.

Another one of the commands, given in step 5 that prevents this error message from occurring, is repeated  below.

```
sudo  chmod  go+rw  $PARTID
```

In step 5, a warning is given, which is repeated below.

> Note: This access granted by the chmod command will only last until OS X is rebooted.

BTW, the command without the variable is given below.

```
sudo  chmod  go+rw  /dev/disk0s4
```

One way, to verify you enter the `chmod` command correctly, would be to enter the following command.

```
ls -l /dev/disk0s4
```

In your case, the expected output is shown below.

```
brw-rw-rw-  1 root  operator 1, 4 14 sep 15:38 /dev/disk0s4
```

### The most likely causes of your problem are given below.

- You are not using the default `bash` shell.
- You did not enter the `chown` command.
- You did not enter the `chown` command correctly.
- You were the `root` user when you entered the `chown` command.
- You added extended security information to the file entries.
- You did not enter the `chmod` command.
- You did not enter the `chmod` command correctly.
- You rebooted the operating system.

Comment: I am doing exactly what the guide tells me to do. No reboot, entered the code once more, got 'disk0s4 was already unmounted' as a result. I still get the same message afterwards.

Comment: What does `ls -l /dev/disk0s4` show the file mode (permissions) to be?

Comment: The result I get is:

`brw-rw-rw-  1 root  operator    1,   4 14 sep 15:38 /dev/disk0s4`

Thank you for your help in the past few days, David. Really appreciate it, as it may seem whiney to keep asking questions.

Comment: That looks OK. What does `ls -l bootcamp*` show for ownership? I assume your current directory is `~/Documents/VirtualBox`.

Comment: `ls -l ~/documents/virtualbox/bootcamp*` gives `-rw-------  1 root  staff  37376 14 sep 15:43 /Users/Nick/documents/virtualbox/bootcamp-pt.vmdk` as well as `-rw-------+ 1 root  staff    682 14 sep 15:43 /Users/Nick/documents/virtualbox/bootcamp.vmdk`
.

Comment: This time you have the wrong output. Read my updated answer.