# Bootable usb won't install windows 7

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I have MacBook 4,1 early 2008 and i've made usb bootable (in bootcamp created with iso) and once i reboot, i get "No bootable device -- insert boot disk". After some search, i installed "rEFIt", and when i reboot, and selected my usb, i get the same message. I found answers that says i need disk, not the usb, but i belive there is a way to install windows from usb. Currently i'm running windows 7 on virtualbox and it's very slow because i have 2gb of ram.

Comment: Which operating system is your computer currently running?

Comment: @MatthewN 10.7.5

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to install Windows 7 on a 2008 Mac by using a USB flash drive containing files from the ISO.

The solution would be to burn the ISO file to a DVD, then install using the DVD.

If you do not have a working optical (DVD) drive, the you can use [the solution given here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521).