# Bootcamp "Missing Operating System" on external drive

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

I've been using an external disk drive to use boot camp on my MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012). It's 1TB, so recently I added a partition to store extra files on it (350GB for boot camp, 650GB for storage). However now when I try to boot into my windows partition it says Missing Operating system. Here is some info about my disk drive: (VECTOTECHHS is the storage partition)

```
$ diskutil list disk2
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:               Windows_NTFS BOOTCAMP                378.0 GB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS VECTOTECHSS

$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk2
Disk: /dev/disk2    geometry: 124519/255/63 [2000409264 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 07 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         2 -  738321070] HPFS/QNX/AUX
*2: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 738322432 - 1262084096] HFS+
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: How did you add the new partition?

Comment: I used the disk utility tool in the windows bootcamp to create the partition since the disk utility mac app did not have an option to partition without erasing.

Comment: Is this external drive a USB drive? What is the model year of your MacBook Pro?

Comment: It is a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012), the external drive is a SSD with a usb 3.0 / usb C connector.

Comment: I did not think it was possible to BIOS boot Windows from an external drive.  If it is possible, then the `*` next to the `2` is in the wrong place.

Comment: I followed this tutorial (https://blog.macsales.com/40947-tech-tip-how-to-use-boot-camp-on-an-external-drive/) to set it up. It has been working for a very long time until I partitioned the external drive. Could you clarify what you mean by `the * next to the 2 is in the wrong place` means? What does the star signify, what is the correct place and how can I move it? Thank you!

Comment: The output `fdisk` you posted shows a `*` next to the number `2`. This means partition 2 is flagged in the MBR table as the bootable partition. The `*` should be next to the number `1`, because I assume this is your bootable Windows partition. You can use the `sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk2` command to move the `*`. This command is interactive. The interactive input would be `flag 1`, `quit` and `yes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your posted output, from `sudo fdisk /dev/disk2`, shows a `*` next to the number `2`. This means partition 2 is flagged in the MBR table as the bootable partition. The `*` should be next to the number `1`, because I assume this is your bootable Windows partition. You can use the `sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk2` command to move the `*`. This command is interactive. The interactive input would be `flag 1`, `quit` and `yes`.