# Problem "List volume"

Tags: bootcamp

I'm having a problem with this tutorial, when I have to list volume and assign the volumes to letters. In fact I'm getting only 3 volumes on my cmd.exe (volume 0 W7.X86X64 CD-Rom) 
(volume 1 (RAW Partition 200M "Masked)
(volume 2 BCSS FAT32 Partition 1906M)

I don't have the volume BOOTCAMP.
I have one HDD (where I want to install windows) + one SSD (where is installed mac) on my macbook pro.

Thanks

[No bootable device USB 2.0 MacBook Pro mid 2014](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521)

Comment: Are you using Bootcamp Assistant?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. No I'm following the tutorial : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521

Comment: Which says use Bootcamp Assistant

Comment: Yes but not the app

Comment: Anyway I've found the solution to the problem (I replaced "disk0" with the name of my second disk on my macbook pro, disk2s4)

Comment: What is the model/year of your Mac? What version of Windows are you trying to install? Is Windows 32 or 64 bit? Are your trying to install to an internal or external drive? What version of macOS (OS X)?

Comment: If you've found the solution, please be sure to add it as an answer.  You can accept your own answer (it's good you found the problem!) and that could help other users who face a similar problem.

Comment: Macbook pro retina early 2011. I've solved the problem but after that, when I had to do the "setup" procedure in the windows command, I typed the setup command but it did just nothing. So I detached the virtual thing and I've just installed windows 7x64 with the normal procedure of the installer and it works perfectly ^^ I installed it on my other internal hard drive. Version of Mac Os 10.11