# Unable to boot after installing Windows 7 without Boot Camp

Tags: bootcamp, startup, windows

I can't boot into Windows after installing Windows 7 on my iMac. I need help troubleshooting.

**Background:**
I have an iMac11,1 (27 inch, late 2009, 2,8 Ghz i7, 8 GB RAM, 1 TB FireCura drive). The optical drive is broken so I have been unsuccessful in using Boot Camp. I've tried some alternate approaches to install Windows 7:

**1**) Modifying the .plist in Boot Camp Assistant allows me to create a USB, partition and reboot but I get stuck on a black screen listing "No bootable CD/DVD".

**2**) Same approach as **1** but on reboot pressing `ALT` and choosing my USB boot media. This gives me an error that I can't install on an MBR disk via EFI.

**3**) Partitioning the drive with Disk Utility, creating a 250 GB FAT32 partition. Launching the installer in the same way as **2**. Installer launches, on the disk screen I need to reformat the BOOTCAMP partition to NTFS andafter that all is smooth until reboot where I'm stuck on a grey screen. Holding down `ALT` I can choose to boot into the USB or MacOS with no problems. After installing there is an additional option of EFIBoot with a regular hard drive icon but if I choose that everything freezes. (Which I guess is the same thing that happens after the installer reboots).

I tried approach **3** with Windows 10 which workes fine but I couldn't find working drivers for everything with Windows 10 so I have since removed Windows 10, partitioned and reformatted the drive. I have tried both with 64 bit versions of Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate with the same result.

I would like advice on how to troubleshoot my current situation or tips on alternative approaches to install Windows 7 on my computer.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In the meantime, can I ask you to edit your post to clarify what you're actually asking?

Comment: Installing Windows 7 in EFI mode is [problematic](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/win7-x64-booting-natively-via-efi-no-bios-emulation.696523/).  If you want Windows 7 without using *Boot Camp Assistant* it would be best to manually create hybrid member using [gdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/) and install in bios mode.

Comment: I've tried clarifying my question as per your request.

Comment: I've read through the linked forum post on EFI. Since Windows 10 works that would mean Windows 10 has better EFI support? How would I go about installing in BIOS mode. If I'm not mistaken that's what I tried in **1**. The computer won't detect the install USB and my optical drive is broken.

Comment: Got it to work using the technique listed at [this guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225387/no-bootable-device-usb-2-0-macbook-pro-mid-2014/225521#225521). Not an easy solution but the only thing that worked so far.